# Prove that the number of primes that divide $B=\left \{ \sum_{i=1}^n b_ia_i^n : n\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ is infinite

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I got this interesting question which says

> Let $n\geq 2$ and let $a_1,a_2,\dots ,a_n$ be positive integers (not
> necessarily distinct) such that $(a_1,a_2,\dots ,a_n)=1$ (where $()$
> represents G.C.D.) and not all $a_i$'s are $1$.
>
> Let $b_1,b_2,\dots ,b_n$ be integers (not necessarily distinct).
> Consider the set \begin{equation*} B=\left \{ \sum_{i=1}^n b_ia_i^n :
>  n\in \mathbb{N} \right\} \end{equation*} Now, let \begin{equation*}
>  P=\{p: p \text{ is a prime such that }p|b \text{ for some } b\in B\}
> \end{equation*} Show that the set $P$ is infinite.

I can intuitively understand that if we consider that only a finite number of primes divide
\begin{equation*}
B_{n_0}=\left \{ \sum_{i=1}^n b_ia_i^n : n\in \{1,2,\dots ,n_0\} \right\}
\end{equation*}
then because the $a_i$'s are coprime, *chances are high* that $B_{n_0+1}$ will introduce a new prime factor. This approach looks more concrete if we look at a special case in which all the $b_i$'s are equal.

But, this is just a vague idea. Is it possible to proceed with this (or with any other idea)?

Comment: @JohnOmielan as far as I understand your approach, you are using specific values of $a_i$ and $b_i$, but you need to prove what is asked for all choices of $a_i$ and $b_i$. Did I get you wrong? If yes, please elaborate your approach a little.

Comment: You're welcome for the welcome :-) . Regarding your question, I believe it's somewhat poorly worded. Part of what confused me is the use of $n$ initially as an apparently fixed value and then again in defining the set $B$ as the power of $a_i$. I believe that second usage was meant to be a different variable. Your question would be clearer and make more sense to me, plus at least to me it'll then be unambiguous as well, if you use something like $B = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n b_ia_i^m : m \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan :) That was a nice suggestion. I did the edit. Is that okay now?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, except you used $m$ as the upper limit for the summation instead of $n$. Note there are always $n$ values of $a_i$, so as my comment showed, that should remain the same. It's incorrect to use $m$ as the upper limit, especially if $m > n$, since then it doesn't make sense for any $a_i$ where $i \gt n$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan The idea of the question, as far as I ubderstand it, is that $n$ is not really fixed. The question seems to ask you to prove that no matter what the choice of $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s (subject to the given conditions), as $n$ goes to infinity, i.e., as more and more $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are taken into consideration, newer primes start dividing the elements of $B$. Now, I feel like it was better with the $n$ instead of the $m$ :(

Comment: Yes, you're right in a way that $n$ is not fixed. However, the idea seems to be that for some $n \ge 2$, whatever it might be (i.e., it's not fixed over all cases, but just for each particular case), you take those $n$ elements of $a_i$ and $b_i$ to create a set of $B$, where each value is the sum of those $n$ elements with each $a_i$ to the $m$'th power. The problem with the original problem statement is that $n$ is initially fixed (you can't defined a variable length set of elements), but then in $B$ it's defined to be variable, i.e., $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: But then why do you think the upper limit of the sum should not be $m$?

Comment: As I mentioned in my earlier comment, having $m$ as the upper limit doesn't make sense since, with $m \in \mathbb{N}$, there is no upper limit for it.  Thus, for any particular case for a specific $n$, when $m \gt n$, then $a_i$ for $i \gt n$ is not defined. I've tried to explain what my issues are & how to address this as best as I can. Unfortunately, I'm afraid I don't have the time or interest in trying to explain this to you any further, so please decide for yourself what you think the question actually means, how to best present it and then edit your question text accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $n \geq 2$, the numbers $a_i^n, 1 \leq i \leq n$ are coprime (as $a_i$s are coprime ). Hence $B=\mathbb{Z}$ which has infinitely many primes.

Answer (score -2):

At first note that $B$ is a collection of integers $b$ of the form $b=p_1^{i_1}p_2^{i_2} \cdots p_m^{i_m}$ because of unique prime factorizations of each $b \in B$, where $p_j, 
 j=1,2,..., m$ are primes and $i_1, i_2, ..., i_m$ are positive integers.

So each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ corresponds to an element $b=p_1^{i_1}p_2^{i_2} \cdots p_n^{i_n} \in B$, say, depending on that fixed $n$. All these primes $p_1,p_2, ...,p_n \in P$ because $p_i ~|~b$ for all $i=1,2,...,n$. Since $\mathbb{N}$ being countably infinite, $P$ must be countably infinite at least.

Comment: Can someone point-out the reason of downvoting ?

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted, but I don't understand your approach. As far as I understand, if you go on adding elements, it may not add a new prime factor in all cases, e.g., suppose you have $\{3,5\}$ and you add $2$ to the set, then no new prime factor is introduced in $3+5=8=2^3$. Also, all infinite sets may not have infinite prime factors, e.g., consider $\{2^n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ which has only one prime factor, $2$. Also, in your question, there's no mention of any $a_i$. Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: @SayanDutta, yes, that is a good point. I think, if we can show that $B$ contains infinitely many elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, then we are done. Let me think whether I can get it

Comment: @SayanDutta, fix $n=2$, then the general element in $B$ is $b=b_1a_1^2+b_2a_2^2$. Take $a_1=1$ and $a_2=2$ so that $(a_1,a_2)=1$. Also $b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Take $b_2=0$, then we get $b=b_1$, where $b_1$ can be any integers. This says that $B \supset \mathbb{Z}$. Since the primes of $\mathbb{Z}$ has infinitely many primes, $P$ is infinite looking at my answer

Comment: that was a nice idea, but isn't it a little too strong? I mean, will that really be correct? For a given choice of $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s, will $B$ contain all elements of $\mathbb{Z}$? Of course, if I give you any $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, you can find $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x$ can be written as the required sum. But, will that hold for **all possible choices** of $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s? I don't think so.

Comment: I don't think the question asks you to choose specific $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s such that the property holds. I think it asks you prove that no matter what their choices (that is given any choice of $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s subject to the given conditions), as $n$ goes to infinity, more and more prime factors start dividing elements of $B$.

Comment: @SayanDutta, i understand what you are saying. But is there anymore restrictions in the original question ? I mean, is that all you mentioned in the question ?

Comment: The question I posted is all that I got. And considering the source from which I got it, chances are very slim that the question missed something.